# Excel link in Word docx

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, bookmarks, links

I use a Word file to put it as a report in which I integrate tables and charts from an Excel file.

More precisely, on a network drive I have many Excel and Word files. Each Word file has its Excel one.

I integrates Excel elements into Word file via this kind of link

{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "\\myserver\myfile.xslx" mySheet!MyRange \a \f 4 \h * MERGEFORMAT }

This works except for a few details :
- I would like to make the path to the file variable so it is sufficient to change an item in the Word file so that all connections use the correct Excel file
Is this possible with a bookmark or any other item that contains the network path and I would use for example as follows:
code:
Select All - View in a separate window

{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "myBookmark" \a \f 4 \h * MERGEFORMAT }

- When I join a link as an image and I manually change the source file (via ALT + F9 and then manually changing the link), the update works .
  As against , in the case of a connection with the preservation of Source Formatting , the update does not happen.
  I observed this problem if the Excel and Word documents are stored on the network. Locally, I do not have this problem.

For more information:
- My version of Word and Excel: 14.0.7106.5003 ( 32bit )

Do you have any tracks for one or the other of these issues?

In advance thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can embed fields within field codes:

[image: Word snip]

The first field in the image shows the field codes used to get the field result of "A" in the second field.

Set up one or more bookmarks pointing to the appropriate text:

```
"\\myserver\myfile.xslx" mySheet!MyRange
```

The Excel link should then work using an embedded field with syntax something like:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 { REF myBookmark } \a \f 4 \h * MERGEFORMAT }
```